# Need to get sessions with Trimou template (Mustache)

Tags: java, spring, mustache

I'm using Spring MVC for my application with [Trimou](http://trimou.org/) (generator to templating) and I have a problem.

I record my logging information in this variable session :

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("User")
```

Is it possible to get this in the Trimou template?

Thx for your help.

Doc Donkun

Answer (score 0):

are you using Spring MVC Trimou extension? If so, you should be able to expose all all the session attributes - see also [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateViewResolver.setExposeSessionAttributes()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractTemplateViewResolver.java#AbstractTemplateViewResolver.setExposeSessionAttributes%28boolean%29). The other possibility would be to expose the HTTP request manually (put in the model) and use [InvokeHelper](https://github.com/trimou/trimou/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/trimou/handlebars/InvokeHelper.java): `{{invoke 'User' method='getAttribute' on=request.session}}`. Or create a [custom helper](http://trimou.org/doc/latest.html#custom_helpers) to get the information.

Martin